# InversifyJS @multiInject a key value map

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

I'm trying to create a Ninja with InversifyJS. Lets say my Ninja can fight with a several weapons at once. I can implement it with @multiInject() decorator:

```
@injectable()
class Ninja implements Warrior {

   private _weapons: Weapon[];

   public constructor(
       @multiInject(TYPES.Weapon) weapons: Weapon[],
   ) {
       this._weapons = weapons;
   }

   public fight() {
       this._weapons.forEach( weapon => weapon.fight());
   }

}

container.bind(TYPES.Weapon).to(Katana);
container.bind(TYPES.Weapon).to(Shuriken);
```

It's ok if I store my weapons as an array. But what if I want to store them as a key value pair?

```
private _weapons: { [weaponId: string]: Weapon };

...

public fight() {
    this._weapons["katana"].fight();
    this._weapons["shuriken"].fight();
}
```

How can I implement this with Inversify?